# Different Ubuntu versions binary execution differences

Tags: c++, assembly, ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-16.04, x86-64

I have the code:

```
#include <iostream>

void func3()
{
  std::cout << "World!" << std::endl;
}

void func2()
{
  std::cout << "Hello ";
}

void func1()
{
  register long int a asm("rbp");
  long int* ptr = (long int*)(a);
  *(ptr+1) = (long int)&func2;
}

int main()
{
  func1();
  func3();

  return 0;
}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is overwrite **return address** of `func1` so it starts executing `func2` after return.

It works just fine on my Ubuntu 16.04 and produces **"Hello "** as output.
However if i run the same code on Ubuntu 14.04 it will crash with **Segmentation Fault** even with `-fno-stack-protector` option.

Why does this happen? How to make it run on 14.04?

> Compiler: gcc 7.3.0
>
> GCC options: -fno-stack-protector
>
> Architecture: x86-64 Intel

Comment: As you can see, whatever you are trying to achieve is heavily platform-dependent. So what do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: Messing with data like that is *always* [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Therefore speculating about behavior is useless. However, for practical reasons, this is highly platform (OS, compiler and hardware) specific.

Comment: Why should it work? It's not valid C++.

Comment: after Q edit: where should then go `func2` after end? You can do `void f1() { f2(); }` ... there's no "return address" or "stack" in C++, what you are currently modifying are implementation details of particular platform + compiler version + compiler options and it may break with any subtle change in any of those.

Comment: @Ped7g there is still return address of main

Comment: @toozyfuzzy where? How do you know there is? There may be other data in stack between, or the return from main may be implemented by different means. None of that is defined in C++, so what you are trying is tinkering with particular machine code on particular platform and particular compiler version+options, for other combination like Ubuntu 14.04 you will have to create new exploit tinkering with the specific code which is produced on 14.04... if you're trying to exploit specific bug in platform/compiler, what you are doing is ok. If you're trying to write some app in C++, it's pointless.

Comment: @Ped7g - Okay, it's not standard C++. This is all based on GNU extensions, indeed. Doesn't mean this is pointless or a bad question.

Comment: @StoryTeller the effort is pointless, once he will get working example on Ubuntu 14.04, and he will change the source to have more code in `main` or `f1`, it may break. Or after compiler update. Or after changing compiling options. Etc.. so why even bother to make it work in very specific case. Plus there's no point to achieve that, to create some kind of "retpoline" you would need more robust approach, for ROP exploits it is OK to work only on particular version/situation, and if some generic legit variant would be done in other case, it will suffer performance penalties (compared to `f2();`)

Comment: @Ped7g - You seem to be overlooking the biggest point here: Education. Why are you so adamant to prevent the OP from tinkering and learning? Even (spectacular) failure has merit. If you clean rant from your comments, I think they'd even make a good answer.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm not against tinkering, I'm wondering why the OP even get the idea that it will work and what's the thinking process behind that, because what he is trying to do is basically assembly/machine code level tinkering, but he's mixing it with C++, which makes the whole situation "will never work properly". If he's interested into exploring how x86 assembly works, he should rather write ordinary assembly source, where properly written "retpoline" will work as expected and everything is well defined, so it would be much easier to provide some stable solutions/answers for questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The real question is how this *did* work with 16.04.  With `gcc -O0`, you end up using the value in `rbp` on entry to `main` *as a return address from `func2`*.

Your program happens to work for me on Arch Linux, with their glibc 2.26-11 package, because its `__libc_start_main` happens to leave the address of `__libc_csu_init` in `rbp` when it calls `main`.  So `__libc_csu_init` runs one extra time (consuming that return address from the stack), then it returns to `<__libc_start_main+234>` in libc.so.6 (the instruction after the `call rax` that calls `main`).  From there, execution continues exactly as if `main` had returned normally, so the cleanup code flushes the stdio / iostream buffers which eventually makes a `write` system call to write `Hello` to stdout.

You can see [how the code compiles on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'//+Arch+Linux+gcc7.3+is+configured+to+make+PIE+executables+by+default%0D%0A//+IDK+how+Ubuntu16.04!'s+gcc5.3+is+configured.%0D%0A%0D%0A//+The+differences+don!'t+matter+in+this+case,+though,%0D%0A//+and+the+code-gen+is+identical+if+you+use+no-pie+for+both.%0D%0A%0D%0A%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Avoid+func3()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22World!!%22+%3C%3C+std::endl%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avoid+func2()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++std::cout+%3C%3C+%22Hello+%22%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avoid+func1()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++register+long+int+a+asm(%22rbp%22)%3B%0D%0A++long+int*+ptr+%3D+(long+int*)(a)%3B%0D%0A++*(ptr%2B1)+%3D+(long+int)%26func2%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aint+main()%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A++func1()%3B%0D%0A++func3()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A++return+0%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:38.38393654003561,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g73,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O0+-fPIE',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+7.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:30.302060405949643,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g530,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O0+-fno-pie',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+5.3+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),header:(),k:31.314003054014748,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), or of course look at your own binaries with `objdump` or single-step through it with `gdb`.

**So it's pure luck that your program ever works anywhere (because of stuff main's caller leaves in registers).  You should expect it to break.**

Of course, this only applies with `gcc -O0`, which enables `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, and doesn't inline functions.  **Both of these assumptions are violated if you compile normally (with `-O3`),** so your code is totally bogus / unsafe and useful only for silly computer tricks where you lie to the compiler and trick it.  This kind of thing sometimes works with `-O0` because it compiles each C statement separately, not keeping any values in registers.

**`foo asm("rbp")` is only guaranteed to do anything when `foo` is used as an operand to an Extended `asm()` statement**.  [Other uses of local register-asm variables are not supported.](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html)  It does appear to be doing what you want in this case, though.

**"Returning" to the start of a different function is totally bogus**.  `ret` pops the return address off the stack, so you enter the next function with `RSP` pointing to whatever *your* caller left on the stack above your return address.  The target function will of course eventually use that as a return address, because it's expecting to be called with `call` (which is equivalent to `push ret_addr` / `jmp`).

In this case, most versions of gcc won't allocate any extra space in `main`, and will just do `push rbp` / ... / `call func1`.  On entry to `func1` the stack holds the return address (into the middle of `main`), and `main`'s saved RBP value.

I assume it breaks on your Ubuntu 14.04 because your libc is compiled differently, and doesn't leave a useful function pointer in RBP the way my Arch system does (which I'm guessing is similar to what your Ubuntu 16.04 system's libc does).

---

#### Tailcall optimization:

Normally if you want to go from one function directly to another without executing `ret` / `call`, you end a function with `jmp func2` instead of `ret`.  There's no way to get this with inline asm, because the compiler won't put your code after the `pop rbp`.

```
func1:
    do stuff
     ...
    jmp  func2
```

vs.

```
  ...
  call  func2
  ret
```

Notice that func2 is entered with the stack identical to how it was on entry to func1, so when `func2` runs a `ret` instruction at the end, it will return to `func1`'s caller.  You're just cutting out the middle man by replacing `call` / `ret` with `jmp`, because those operations balance each other.  As a bonus, it doesn't even break the return-address predictor, because `ret`s still match up with `call`s.

---

**Exploring with a debugger**:

In GDB, I used **`display *(void **) $rsp @ 4`** to have gdb print the top 4 values on the stack after every single-step.  Using `void*` gets GDB to print them as pointers, tagged them with a symbol name if they're within a known function, so it's really handy for seeing return addresses.

I looked at `/proc/PID/maps` to see that `0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>` was in `/usr/lib/libc-2.26.so`.

I set a breakpoint on the `push rbp` at the start of main (instead of after the function prologue  where `b main` would put one).  At that point:

```
Breakpoint 2, main () at ret-frob.cpp:41
1: *(void **) $rsp @ 4 = {0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>, 0x11c00, 0x7fffffffe6e8, 0x1ffffe6f8}
(gdb) p (void*)$rbp
$9 = (void *) 0x5555555549c0 <__libc_csu_init>
```

As you can see, `main`'s normal return address is to `0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>`.  That's where the libc function that called `main` has told it to return.  Doing anything else violates the calling convention.  (Except calling `exit` or `_exit`, or some other way of never returning at all).

I used `layout reg` to put GDB into a text-UI mode where it shows the instructions you're stepping through in a separate "window" from the commands.  (See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more GDB tips).

After a couple `si` (stepi) commands to single-step by one instruction, we're at the top of `func1`.  main has run `push rbp` / `call func1`:

```
func1 () at ret-frob.cpp:27
1: *(void **) $rsp @ 4 = {0x55555555494c <main()+9>, 0x5555555549c0 <__libc_csu_init>, 0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>, 0x11c00}
```

When func1 is about the `ret`:

```
1: *(void **) $rsp @ 4 = {0x555555554909 <func2()>, 0x5555555549c0 <__libc_csu_init>, 0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>, 0x11c00}
```

**After `func1` runs `ret`, on entry to `func2`:**

```
1: *(void **) $rsp @ 4 = {0x5555555549c0 <__libc_csu_init>, 0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>, 0x11c00, 0x7fffffffe6e8}
```

So `func2` has called with a return address of `0x5555555549c0 <__libc_csu_init>`.

And `$rsp = 0x7fffffffe600`, so the stack is misaligned.  (It's supposed to be 16-byte aligned *before* a `call`, so `rsp` is 8 bytes away from 16-byte alignment on function entry.  (Note that a `jmp` tailcall maintains this.)

I used `ni` (next-instruction) to step over the `call _ZStlsISt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIcT_ES5_PKc@plt` because I don't care about all that code and the lazy dynamic linker resolution stuff.

**Before `ret` from `func2`**:

```
1: *(void **) $rsp @ 4 = {0x5555555549c0 <__libc_csu_init>, 0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>, 0x11c00, 0x7fffffffe6e8}
```

**On entry to `__libc_csu_init`**:

```
1: *(void **) $rsp @ 4 = {0x7ffff7157f4a <__libc_start_main+234>, 0x11c00, 0x7fffffffe6e8, 0x1ffffe6f8}
```

So main+func1+func2 have effectively tail-called `__libc_csu_init`, and it will return to `main`'s caller after running.  (And redoing init of iostream stuff, and so on.  It's lucky that this function doesn't clobber the I/O buffer that's still holding the `Hello` string!  Maybe it checks for stuff already being initialized in case it's called twice for some other reason.)

**TL:DR your code is super broken, of course it fails on some systems.**

Comment: Thanks for such a comprehensive answer!  Your stackoverflow profile is just a treasury of great material, just, wow!

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this happen?

Because compiler is free to produce invalid code, when the source is "undefined behaviour", your source is not well-defined C++ and the compiler decided to produce machine code which does crash.

Even after my comments you didn't bother to enlighten us why do you think it should work and which thinking process brought you to this source (what problem you are trying to solve by changing return address of `f1`), so I can't explain this more, except you are trying to run invalid source, and you get crash as result, which is pretty normal behaviour of C++ ecosystem, happens way too often even when you actually try to avoid it and write valid C++, as that's not *that* simple.

Keep in mind the `rbp` register, stack pointer, stack memory, stack alignment, and `ret` instructions are not part of C++ language, and there's no definition requiring the C++ compiler to use the stack in expected way to control the flow of the code, the C++ compiler may as well decide to you use self-modifying jumps, if it wants, so the return address would never appear on the stack at all and you would have to patch the jump. While this is very unlikely and you can expect x86 code to use `call+ret` pairs, anything else assuming about the state of stack in C++ source is pointless, the underlying implementation may easily put into stack something you don't expect.

> How to make it run on 14.04?

Launch it in debugger and check yourself how the original code (without modifying stack content) works, and what has to be modified on stack to make `f1` jump into `f2`. It's probably some padding or useless preserved stack space making the structure of stack between `f1` and `f2` incompatible, so by some patching of the stack content you can surely achieve what you want (for particular source with particular compilation options).

It's of course not a stable solution, i.e. it will surely break after adding some more code to `f1`, `f2` or `main`, probably just few local variables in each will break your tampering, not even mentioning switching *on* optimizer, which would probably remove the empty functions completely.

---

What you are trying to do is somewhat similar to "retpoline", so you can check discussions around that and linux kernel sources to see a practical real world problem solution (somewhat mitigating the security vulnerability for the hefty performance price), which is as far as I can tell the only legitimate reason for doing something like that, as return address tampering will make the internal return address buffer in modern x86 CPU out-of-sync, which makes the next `ret` instruction very costly in terms of performance.

(**EDIT**: The CPU will speculatively execute return path into `main` upon sniffing the `ret` incoming - from it's internal return address buffer, and at the moment of actual `ret` execution it will figure out the address didn't match, so it will throw out the whole speculative path and fetch+execute the correct code path into `f2` instead, which costs several cycles of CPU to reload the caches and buffers with the unexpected code path and not being able to use the work already done ahead on the speculative path)

So if your motivation was like to avoid one `ret` in `f1` to return to `main` and `call f2` in the `main`, saving one `ret+call` pair of instructions, to make the code faster, you are making it actually much slower in practice, due to internal complexity of modern x86 CPU, which doesn't operate as simply per-instruction, as the original 8086 did.

For performance reasons keep the source like this:

```cpp
void f1() { /* ... some code ... */ }

void f2() { /* ... some code ... */ }

void main() {
  f1();
  f2();
}
```

or

```cpp
void f2() { /* ... some code ... */ }

void f1() {
  /* ... some code ... */
  f2();
}

void main() {
  f1();
}
```

A modern C++ compiler with optimizing *on* will highly likely inline both `f1` and `f2` into `main` in this trivial case, weighting the pros and cons of such inlining in particular case (also avoiding excessive inlining in situations where it would cause more damage than profit).

Comment: `gcc -O0` for x86-64 enabled `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, and doesn't inline functions.  The problems are: 1) `foo asm("rbp")` is only guaranteed to do anything when `foo` is used as an operand to an Extended `asm()` statement.  2) "returning" to the start of a different function is totally bogus, because as you say you have no control over what code gcc emits for `main`.  You'd expect `main` to `push rbp` / `call func1`, so having `func1` "return" to `func2` would enter that function with something other than a return address on the stack.